# When will an index be created for a column?

Tags: list, indexed-column

I have a SharePoint 2007 List and it has almost 10 columns and 1000+ items, I want to enable the Index for a specific column is in the list. If I enable the index now then when it will create an index for that column? Is there a way to kick of the indexing process manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually start a crawl by going to

1. Shared Services - > search settings -> Content sources and crawl schedules

**Start full Crawl** or **Start Incremental Crawl**

Take a look at this technet article too : [Crawl content (Office SharePoint Server 2007)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262794%28office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: is that mean index will be created during the incremental or full crawl?

Comment: You can read about the diff here : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointsearch/thread/af86399b-c1e7-4f1b-a54e-2aaafa55b173 I think incremental crawl would be enough in your case.